# How can I create a smooth jump to section on a horizontally scrolling page?

Tags: jquery, scroll, page-jump

I am building my portfolio website for my photography business. I've built the site so the portfolios scroll horizontally.

This is what I have so far.
http://www.dscottclarkphoto.com/portfolio/adventure/adventure.html

I would like to be able to include arrows that when clicked jump the viewer to the next photograph.

I tried using what was demonstrated in this:
[jQuery: jump to next <section>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906001/jquery-jump-to-next-section)

I saved the Javascript into it's own file named jump.js.

```
<script src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jump.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="images">
 <ul> 
    <li><section id="1"><img src="../space.jpg" /></section></li>
    <li><section id="2"><img src="adventure/adv-01.jpg" /></section></li>
    <li><section id="3"><img src="adventure/adv-02.jpg" /></section></li>
    <li><section id="4"><img src="adventure/adv-03.jpg" /></section></li>
    <li><section id="5"><img src="adventure/adv-04.jpg" /></section></li>
  </ul>
```

I also tried saving the sample and it is not behaving correctly either.

```
</div>
```

Are there any suggestions on how to make this work or a better method?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code. It works exactly as you want.

```
$(function(){
    var currentImage = 1;
    var imagesCount = $('#images li').length - 1;
    var spacerWidth = $('#images li:eq(1)').offset().left;
    $('#scroll').click(function(){
        currentImage++;
        if (currentImage == imagesCount) currentImage = 1;
        var left = $('#images li').eq(currentImage).offset().left;
        $(window).scrollLeft(left - spacerWidth);
    });
});
```

When you add an appropriate button for scrolling just change `$('#scroll')` to its selector. Now it is attached to "scroll this way >" text.

And note that you don't need to add any extra markup like `<section>` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you posted they are using vertical scrolling (`$(myEl).offset().top`) if you are using horizontal scrolling you should change that for `$(myEl).offset().left`.
Didn't try it but it should be that.
Also, nothing to do with the question but it might help to improve the look of your page, you might want to save the images as `*.png interlaced` so they don't slide down as they are currently doing.

Comment: Thank you. what do you mean by the images are sliding down?

Comment: They literally show up progressively from top to bottom, that's because the way they were saved. You might want to re-save them as `*.png interlaced` or `*.jpg progressive` You won't see it because they are already cached on your browser... this will improve the look and UX a lot with little to no work.