# How can i implement sequence section scroll when click only one specific link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

[Please check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJUjY.png)

When user click on this arrow it will go to next section and next click it will go next section. in short sequence section scroll every time user click on down arrow

Here is my HTML

```
<section id="intro">

</section>

<section id="about-us">

</section>

<section id="services">

</section>

<section id="team">

</section>

<section id="contact">

</section>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: where is your code, what have you tried?

Comment: sorry:( just added screenshot. please check now :)

Comment: and you js, in a more manageable format

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking a question, it is always very helpful to include code—please do not share code in screenshots, because it makes it very difficult to copy and reproduce. It helps tremendously if you can create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example using the code snippet function.

Comment: thanks @Terry just did

Comment: What about the JavaScript that you have tried?

Comment: i don't know JS well. that's why i asking how can i do that :(

Answer (score 0):

someone created something very similar to what you require, check it out:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
    });
  }
});

// Scroll to "about" section
$('#about').scrollTo('fast', 'linear');
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.next-section').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $next = $this.parent().next();

    $next.scrollTo($next.offset().top, 500, 'linear');
});

$('.prev-section').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $prev = $this.parent().prev();

    $prev.scrollTo($prev.offset().top, 500, 'linear');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="about">
    <a href="#" class="prev-section">Previous Section</a>
    <a href="#" class="next-section">Next Section</a>
    <div class="section-content">
        Foobar
    </div>
</section>
```

**Original Post:**

[Stackoverflow Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906001/jquery-jump-to-next-section)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Xdg2k/)

Comment: thank you so much for you answer. but it's not something i looking for :( . i want sequence section scroll when click only one specific link